# Centos 7 Network Not Coming Up

Tags: networking, centos

I have two physical machines that have dual NICs. One is running CentOS 6 and one was just upgraded to CentOS 7. I have the two NIC's bonded:

```
TYPE=Bond
DEVICE=bond0
NAME=bond0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
BONDING_OPTS="mode=active-backup"
IPADDR=10.8.8.35
PREFIX=21
GATEWAY=10.8.8.1
```

All links (including bond0) come up without errors. But when I attempt to ping ANY IP on my network it fails with "Destination Host Unreachable".

ip route is also the same for both servers. Everything looks the same to me. **How can I determine why my packets aren't leaving my system?**

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it's a typo, but **TYPE=bond0** should be: **TYPE=Bond**

Try changing this and restarting the networking service.

Comment: You're right. bond0 was a typo but it was my typo. I'm having to copy by hand while connected directly to the box as I can't SSH into it (no network). I corrected the question.